# return statement in void function in C

Tags: c, function, return, void

In the following program, **Why compiler does not gives any error or warning?**

```
cc -Wall -pedantic my_program.c
```

**code here:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f()
{
        return; // return statement in void function
}

int main()
{
        f();
        return 0;
}
```

I have compiled the program in **GCC** compiler on **Linux** platform.

Comment: Because it's perfectly legal? You could've looked it up.

Comment: Because it's perfectly fine to `return` from a `void` function. What error/warning do you expect?

Comment: Please don't downvote on the grounds of obviousness, as that's subjective. The OP has written this question carefully, with a code snippet.

Comment: @Bathsheba  In the same way he can ask why `int a = 22 / 7;` does not generate warning.

Comment: You should read a C book.

Comment: a `return` statement, with no value is normal when wanting to exit a `void` function before reaching the end of the function.   This example is no different.  A problem would only surface if the `return` statement has a value attached I.E. `return 0` would be invalid for a `void` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course you can use `return;` in a `void` function. How else would you return early from such a function?

In your case the statement is redundant as it's reached on all control paths, but a compiler will certainly not issue a diagnostic in that instance.

(Note that you **must** `return` explicitly from a non-`void` function, with the exception of `main()`, where a compiler must generate `return 0;` if missing.

Answer (score 1):

A void function will perform the task, and then control returns back to the caller but, it's not going to return a value. There isn't any value to return.

Without the return statement, control will return to the caller at the end of the function anyways.